# Log4J RollingFileAppender not enforcing max log size

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I'm working with Log4j as our logging solution. The issue encountered is that the `RollingFileAppender` is not behaving consistently across all environments.

Configuration code:

```
        try {
            RollingFileAppender a = new RollingFileAppender( layout, s_file, true ) ;
            a.setName( "RollingFileAppender" ) ;
            a.setMaxFileSize( "1MB" ) ;
            a.setMaxBackupIndex( 32 ) ;
            a.setImmediateFlush( true ) ;
            a.setBufferedIO( false ) ;
            a.setBufferSize( 1024 ) ;
            s_Logger.addAppender( a ) ;
        } catch( IOException ioe ) {
            ioe.printStackTrace() ;
        }
```

The issue is that, in the development environment and all test environments, the file size limits to ~1024kb as expected. In the production environment, the file is north of 500mb already.

This is deployed on a Tomcat 7.0.52 environment across all instances.
Is there a Tomcat configuration that would interfere with how Log4j handles it's files?

Folder permissions match in all instances.

Comment: Are you using the `log4j.properties` file?

Comment: No, the log4j.properties is not being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to shut down the tomcat instance, delete the large log file and restart the server. It is now producing 1mb files as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `activateOptions()` on RollingFileAppender after setting the values, e.g.:

```
...
a.setBufferSize( 1024 ) ;
a.activateOptions() ;  // Call it here
s_Logger.addAppender( a ) ;
....
```

Comment: Thanks, we've resolved the issue without finding an actual cause, but I'll look at implementing this solution if the problem repeats.